# Mozilla Prism: disable pop-up blocker

Tags: javascript, prism, mozilla-prism

I'm developing an application using Mozilla Prism. Unfortunately, Prism has its pop-up blocker activated.

I tried to disable it by inserting a line like

> user_pref("privacy.popups.policy", "1");

or

> `user_pref("dom.disable_open_during_load", false);`

into the webapp.js, which resides in the directory of the Prism application. However, this did not work, pop-ups are still not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bug about this you can vote/comment on here.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=503841

adam

Answer (score 0):

I added the following lines inside **prefs.js** located in

*For Win XP:* /Documents and Settings/[username]/Application Data/Prism/[app name]/Profiles/[prism profile name]/

*For Vista:* /Users/[username]/AppData/Roaming/Prism/[app name]/Profiles/[prism profile name]/

```
user_pref("dom.disable_open_during_load", false);
user_pref("capability.policy.default.Window.open", "allAccess");
```

**Make sure your Prism application is closed before making these changes** because it will overwrite the prefs.js on close, wiping out your changes.

Finally - I can use the Gmail Create Event button to create events from my Gmail Prism app.

Comment: Yay! I've been looking for this for months!